# Unable to run Robolectric unit test with debugger in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I've been successfully running Robolectric unit tests under the debugger in Android Studio since version 0.6.1

Now I am unable to and get the following error

```
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750] 
Could not write standard input into: Gradle Test Executor 1.
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

I have always set the use `in-process build` flag unchecked in the compile settings and although I am currently using AS 0.8-14, I have gone back and tried 0.8-11, 0.8-9 and 0.6-1 and none of them work now.  I'm using android build tools version 19.1.0 (and have been for some time and it does work with them).

Could it be some local security setting under Mac OS X?  Any assistance would be gratefully received.

** Update **
I have discovered that the issue is caused by running an additional JavaExec task before running the unit test tasks.  It seems that gradle is running the JVM for the first task and passing debug arguments to it e.g. `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=49807`  The task completes and the JVM exits.  Gradle then runs the actual unit test and expects the new JVM to listen on the same port for the debugger to connect - which it doesn't and so the connection failure arises.

How can I either prevent the prior task (an ormlite database compile task) from running under the debugger or force gradle to recognise that the unit test task will run using a new JVM and so change the jvmArgs for the unit test to reflect the new debug port?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the database compilation task to be an `Exec` task rather than a `JavaExec` task.  The exec task was defined as follows and so executed the database compilation as an external java process, not a gradle invoked one.  This prevented the debug JVM being 'consumed' by the database compilation task.

```
task (taskName type: Exec) {
    def mainClass = "com.some.class"
    def classPath = "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${flavorName}/${buildType.name}" + ":" + configurations.databaseCompile.asPath
    commandLine "java", "-cp", classPath, mainClass, configDirName
}
```